# How to call my paintComponent() method in another class

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent, drawimage

I am writing a Blackjack program which at some point, calls a paintComponent() method to draw an image from a file. The picture is suppose to appear in a JPanel, but if I try to call the method on that `JPanel-> style2b1.paintComponent(getGraphics())`;

It doesn't work (`NullPointerException`), but that in itself doesn't surprise me. The only thing that I have tried and that didn't gave me any error was to simply write : `paintComponent(getGraphics())`;

But the image wasn't displayed either.

Like I said earlier I tried a bunch of different calls, with different things as parameters but it never gave positive results.

My class Windows

```
package com;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Windows extends JFrame{


JFrame test = new JFrame();
JLabel text = new JLabel("Welcome to Blackjack 21");
JLabel textAction = new JLabel("");
JLabel textBank = new JLabel("BANK");
JLabel textPlayer = new JLabel("PLAYER");
JPanel style = new JPanel();
JPanel style2 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
JPanel style2a = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
JPanel style2a1 = new JPanel();
JPanel style2a2 = new JPanel();
JPanel style2b = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
JPanel style2b1 = new JPanel();
JPanel style2b2 = new JPanel();
JPanel style3 = new JPanel();
JButton b1 = new JButton("Stand");
JButton b2 = new JButton("Hit");
JButton b3 = new JButton("Double");
JButton b4 = new JButton("Split");
JButton b5 = new JButton("Insurance");
Font font = new Font("Helvetica", 10, 20);


public Windows(){
   style.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
   style2.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
   style2a.setBackground(Color.magenta);
   style2a1.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
   style2a2.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
   style2b.setBackground(Color.magenta);
   style2b1.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
   style2b2.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
   style3.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
   style3.add(b1);
   style3.add(b2);
   style3.add(b3);
   style3.add(b4);
   style3.add(b5);
   text.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
   text.setFont(font);
   style.add(text);
   textAction.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
   textAction.setFont(font);
   style2.add(textAction);
   textBank.setFont(font);
   textBank.setForeground(Color.RED);
   style2a1.add(textBank);
   textPlayer.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
   textPlayer.setFont(font);
   style2b2.add(textPlayer);
   style2b1.setSize(this.getWidth(), 300);
   DrawPicture otaku = new DrawPicture();

   b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
       @Override
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           textAction.setText("You choose to stand. You won't receive any more cards.");
       }
   });
   b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
       @Override
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           textAction.setText("You choose to hit. You will receive another card");
//This is where I want to call my method
           paintComponents(getGraphics());
       }
   });
   b3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
       @Override
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           textAction.setText("You choose to double. You will receive one last card and you have to double your bet");
       }
   });
   b4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
       @Override
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           textAction.setText("You choose to split. Each deck of card will be considered as individual, however you have to double your bet ");
       }
   });
   b5.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
       @Override
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           textAction.setText("You choose to raise an insurance. Please double your bet.");
       }
   });


   test.add(style, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
   test.add(style2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
   style2.add(style2a, BorderLayout.NORTH);
   style2a.add(style2a1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
   style2a.add(style2a2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
   style2.add(style2b, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
   style2b.add(style2b1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
   style2b.add(style2b2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
   test.add(style3, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

   test.setSize(1000, 1000);
   test.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   test.setVisible(true);
   test.setLocation(500, 0);
   test.setResizable(false);
}

}
```

My class DrawPicture

```
 package com;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;


public class DrawPicture extends JPanel {

File a = new File("C:\\Users\\km\\Pictures\\Cards\\red_back.png");

public void paintComponents(Graphics g){
    try {
        Image testItOut = ImageIO.read(a);
        g.drawImage(testItOut, 50, 300, this);
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

My aim is to be able to display many pictures (then later regulate their size) in the JPanel style2a2 and JPanel style2b1. I don't know if I can put more than one element by JPanel but I haven't thought that far yet.

[image: How my JFrame looks]

Comment: I am not an English speaker by birth, so please feel free to review my grammar and to change the sentences so that people that have the same problem can easily understand it. Thank you very much

Comment: Your `style2b1`is an object from the class `JPanel` which dosen't have your costum method. To solve this you just need to change the class to your `DrawPicture` and then you will have your method and all of `JPanel` native implementations (because you extended it).

Comment: Unfortunately by doing so it returns a nullPointerExeption at the line g.drawImage(pathToPicture, 50, 300, this);  Is something wrong with the observer ? @JPeter

Comment: Well at least the method is called... now to the next problem... I don't think that you need to escape "\" so the path to your file should be `File("C:\Users\km\Pictures\Cards\red_back.png");`. the easiest way to solve  this kind of problem is using breakpoints (using debug). just get one in that line and check all the variables

Comment: I can't take the "\" away. If I do the program considers it as part of the text and not as a separation between files and I get a syntax error. So I have to leave it like that. Thank you for your help for the drawPicture explaination!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A **paintComponent** (better defined with `@Override` to detect typos) is automatically called during (re)paints of the GUI. So they are *event driven*, reacting. It is not intended to be called straight. Instead use one of the JComponent's `repaint*` methods, either on the DrawPicture variable, or on the entire JFrame (`Windows`).

```
public class DrawPicture extends JPanel {

    private Image testItOut;

    // Access for setting an other image.
    public void setImage(Image testItOut) {
        this.testItOut = testItOut;
    }

    public Image getImage() {
         return testItOut;
    }

    public DrawPicture() {
        try {
            File a = new File("C:\\Users\\km\\Pictures\\Cards\\red_back.png");
            testItOut = ImageIO.read(a);
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        if (testItOut != null) {
            g.drawImage(testItOut, 50, 300, this);
        }
    }
}
```

For instance:

```
b5.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     @Override
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         otaku.repaint(50L); // Repaint after 50 ms.
     }
});
```

This can be shortened with lambdas as:

```
b5.addActionListener(e -> {
   otaku.repaint(50L); // Repaint after 50 ms.
});
```

or even

```
b5.addActionListener(e -> otaku.repaint(50L));
```

A bit more realistic:

```
b5.addActionListener(e ->
   SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
       File imgFile = new File("C:\\Users\\km\\Pictures\\Cards\\green_back.png");
       Image img = ImageIO.read(imgFile);
       otaku.setImage(img);
       otaku.repaint(50L);
}));
```

`invokeLater` makes the GUI behave more responsive when the code of the `actionPerformed` would take longer (it does not block during the button press).